# Distribution of roots of complex polynomials

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I generated random quadratic and cubic polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$
uniformly distributed in the unit disk $|z| \le 1$. The distribution of the roots of 10000
of these polynomials are shown below (left: quadratic; right: cubic).

[image: Poly23]
What explains these distributions? In particular: (1) Why the relative paucity of roots
near the origin. (2) Why is the density concentrated in $\frac{1}{2} \le |z| \le 1$?
(3) Why is the cubic distribution sharper than the quadratic?

Comment: It's probably significant that the distribution of the *product* of the roots, and therefore that of the product of their absolute values, does not depend on the degree.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the logarithm of the roots? This seems to show a density that is independent of the imaginary part and symmetric w.r.t. the real part.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen: Nice insight! But I still don't understand what's driving these distributions...

Comment: Now a revised version of this question [posted on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/139804/6094).

Comment: The distribution of roots is invariant under rotation. More precisely, under the transform $a_k \to e^{ik\theta} a_k$, a root $r$ of the polynomial $z^n + a_1 z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n$ corresponds to a root $r e^{-i\theta}$ of the transformed polynomial. That's why the density is independent of the imaginary part of log of the root.

Comment: could you post a histogram of  generated coefficients? Or please present the method/reasoning that generated coefficients are reasonably uniform.

Comment: Relevant: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week285.html

Comment: First step in studying these distributions is to use the fact that you can rotate all the coefficients by an equal phase and thus rotate the roots by that phase, to meaningfully plot the arg of the roots. Now you have two 1-d distributions, and if the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test says the are not significantly different, your question changes into "what drives that unified distribution, and why aren't they different."

Comment: I know you've probably checked, but is this an artefact of your method for randomly choosing the coefficients?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182412/why-do-roots-of-polynomials-tend-to-have-absolute-value-close-to-1/ for a similar discussion with degree $100$

Answer (score 3):

The first two observations can be explained by the fact that if $r$ is the root of $a_nz^n+\cdots +a_0$ then $r^{-1}$ is the root of $a_0z^n+\cdots +a_n$.  Since the joint probability density of the coefficients is symmetric under $a_k\mapsto a_{n-k}$ transformation the density of the roots should be symmetric under $r\mapsto r^{-1}$.  It should be fairly straightforward to find asymptotic behavior of the density as $z\to0$ or $z\to\infty$. In the first case, $r\to a_0/a_1$ and the second case is symmetric under inversion.

The distribution around $|z|=1$ is less obvious, so I need to think more to explain your third observation.